# How to plot Berry curvature flux by considering plane in momentum space?

Tags: quantum-espresso, topological-insulators, berry-phase, wannier90, weyl-semimetal

I want to plot the berry curvature flux by considering $k_x$ and $k_y$ plane in momentum space. I have experience running DFT calculations in Quantum ESPRESSO. I have tried reading the user manual of Wannier90 tool but didn't find any way to do this. The below image can be referred for more understanding of what I am trying to do:
[image]

I am not asking for actual code but just the steps which I have to follow in Wannier90 to achieve this results. Any help will be appreciable regarding this!
Thank you!

Comment: I gave my +1 a while back, but I wonder: why is it that you're not asking for actual code? Would it be too hard for someone to provide the code? We welcome questions that are a [tag:software-input-file-request]. Sometimes it can be easier to provide code than to explain the steps to follow in order to obtain certain results.

Comment: @Nike Dattani, Thank you for your attention. I thought, providing actual code for an example system might be lengthy. So I asked just for steps that I can follow so that I can explore each step by myself. Thank you for mentioning the [software-input-file-request](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-input-file-request) tag. I will look into it. I will update the answer by myself as soon as I learn it.

Comment: Any update now? Still working on it?